# How to return either Redirect of the same page with model in Rasor?

Tags: razor, return-type, post-redirect-get

In `OnPost` method I have two options

- Success: I need to redirect to view page.
- Failure: I need to return the same page with filled model to show errors to the user.

What should the handler return? IActionResult, something else? Maybe the whole flow is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ...
    return LocalRedirect(...);
}
else
{
    ...
    return Page();
}
```